# Relation between group zero-cohomology and the dual of group zero-homology

Tags: homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Let $\Gamma$ be a group and $A$ be an abelian group and let's take group zero-homology and zero-cohomology, $H_0(\Gamma,A)$, $H^0(\Gamma,A)$. Is there any relation between $H^0(\Gamma,A)$ and $Hom(H_0(\Gamma,A),\mathbb{Z})$? And changing $\mathbb{Z}$ by other group?

Comment: Did you mean for $A$ to be a non-trivial $\Gamma$-module?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any module $M$ the natural quotient map $A \to H_0(\Gamma,A)$ induces 
an isomorphism $Hom(H_0(\Gamma,A),M) \cong H^0(\Gamma,Hom(A,M)).$  (Here
we regard $Hom(A,M)$ as a $\Gamma$-module by the contragredient action.)

Thus, in order to get a relationship between $Hom(H_0(\Gamma,A),\mathbb Z)$
and $H^0(\Gamma,\mathbb Z)$, you would need an isomorphism of $\Gamma$-modules
$A \cong Hom(A,\mathbb Z)$.  For this, $A$ should be a finitely generated free
$\mathbb Z$-action, with a self-dual $\Gamma$-action.